# Is it possible to change the type used in a method of a base class from within a derived class without modifying the base class?

Tags: c#, inheritance, substitution

Suppose we have four classes A, B, T and U, which look something like this:

```
using System;
using bla;


public class T
{
    public void method()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am using T.");
    }
}

public class U : T
{
    public new void method()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am using U.");
        // other stuff...
    }
}

public class A
{
    public T t;
    public void method()
    {
        t = new T();
        t.method();
        // some important manipulations of t...
    }
}

namespace bla{
    using T = U;
    public class B : A
    {
        public new void method()
        {
            // now use type U instead of T in the base method.
            base.method();
            // other stuff...
        }    
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        B b = new B();
        b.method();
    }
}
```

I want to achieve that when the base method `base.method()` is called from within class B actually type U is used and not type T. Such that the output of the `Main()` method would be:

```
I am using U.
```

Is it possible to achieve this in C# **without having to modify class A and/or T**? Something like a using directive would be nice. The above code - obviously - doesn't work as I want. I also thought about using reflection, but I am not sure if it is possible to use reflection in this case without having to instantiate a new (anonymous) object or reference an existing one (both would not be nice in my case).

Otherwise I would have to modify class A (resp. class B as an almost 100% line-by-line copy) by either substituting each T with U or by inserting a using directive at the beginning (or accepting parameters, or using templates, or whatever). Either way I would find this not very neat and I wonder if it is achievable somehow better.

Am I missing something obvious?
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Blimey, this code is a mess. I think you would benefit substantially by going and learning about inheritance (especially the `virtual` keyword) and possibly generics too.

Comment: Did you try using a virtual method in T and overriding that method in U?

Comment: Yes, it's not nice. The thing is that (here) classes T and A are not coded by me and sadly they are not friendly designed towards polymorphism. But I have to build onto them. Sure generics or using the `virtual` keyword would help, but that would require modifications of A and T which I want to avoid if possible.

Comment: I would strongly recommend changing those classes though, there is almost never a good reason to use the `new` keyword to hide functions which is what you are doing here. It's dangerous and confusing.

Comment: I agree with you. Then it seems I have no other option than to adjust these classes to my needs. Thanks anyway.

Comment: If you're working with classes you can't modify, try not to modify them. You could create an adapter pattern or facade pattern for your own code, using new classes that call the old ones.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no, given the current structure, it's not possible to make `base.method()` that's called from `B` to use `method` of `U` instead of `T` without modifying neither `A` nor `T`. However, why won't you just:

```
public class B : A
{
    public new void method()
    {
        U u = new U();
        u.method();
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I also feared that it wouldn't be possible. Why I don't create a new U from within B to call it's method is due to the fact that within `base.method` some other important manipulations on/with T are taking place (which I would like to have on U). That's why it's necessary to call the base method too.

Comment: If, as you suggest, there's definitely no way for you to modify `A`/`T`, then you may want to consider figuring out a way to manipulate a `U` instance from a `T` instance. If that's not 'legal' as well (i.e `T` members' access modifiers won't allow it), reflection might be your last resort.

Comment: It would be possible, it's just not elegant and may result in further adjustments later on. So my question is probably more of academic nature. ^^
One of the reasons why I created `U` was to get access to protected but necessary members of `T`. I don't see a way to manipulate `U` from `T` yet, but thank you for your suggestion. Maybe I'll get an idea along the way.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try it out yet, but you I'm sure casting the object into the base-class you want could help.

Like this:

```
((U)this).method();
```

EDIT: The reason type T is used, instead of type U, is that there there is an instance of type T in class A.

Comment: Perhaps you should try this out then?

Comment: @J.B. Schubert Sadly that doesn't work. :/ But maybe I got that wrong. And yes, type T is explicitly used in class A. But I wonder if it is possible to substitute that from outside A (and T) somehow.

Comment: @Zacryon What you are trying to archive is not possible without changing the class A.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the consensus here. That's unfortunate. I'll manipulate the classes then. Thank you for your help.